# Still don't understand how to add a slack variable in optimal problem

Tags: matlab, cvx

Now I am trying to add a slack variable to this optimal problem: http://ask.cvxr.com/t/why-does-the-optimal-value-become-nan-sometimes/6035

And here is my reference about adding slack variable section 6 in this website https://yalmip.github.io/debugginginfeasible/

And here is the slack code of the website. There are somethings I don't understand about it.

```
slack1 = sdpvar(N,1);
slack2 = sdpvar(N,1);
Constraints = [slack1>=0]
for i = 1:N
 Constraints = [Constraints, something1 <= slack1(i)];
 Constraints = [Constraints, something2 == slack2(i)];
end
```

My questions about the example are:

1. If I have three constraints, do I need to produce three slack variables?
2. Do I need to build Constraints = [slack2>=0] also?
3. What does the "something" mean in his example code? Is it a value, a vector, a matrix or a formula?
4. How do I define the N? In one constraint there is not only one vector but also the other vector, some vectors may be 5 by 1, some may be 4 by 1, so I don't know what value I should assume for N?

Here is my code below, I don't think this is correct, unless I know the explanation of the question I ask, the N I assume is 4, because I only have one kind of vector; 4 by 1 vector

> ```
> slack_for_C3 = sdpvar(4,1);
> slack_for_C5  = sdpvar(4,1);
> slack_for_C10  = sdpvar(4,1);
> Constraints = [ slack_for_C3 >=0]
> for i = 1:4
>  Constraints = [Constraints, something1 <= slack_for_C3(i)];
>  Constraints = [Constraints, something2 == slack_for_C5(i)];
>  Constraints = [Constraints, something3 == slack_for_C10(i)];
> end
> ```

My optimal problem code and formula are as below

[image]

```
 hat_p_up=0.0824
%OP4
%declare
K=4;
N=4;
L=5;%distance between RX & TX
xi=10^-4%tolerence between 
nois_var_hk_2pow=0.1*(L^(-2.5));%W,0.1*(L^(-2.5)),if this unit is dbm
nois_var_ak_2pow=[1.0000e-10 1.0000e-10 1.0000e-10 1.0000e-10 ];
nois_var_dk_2pow=[1.0000e-08 1.0000e-08 1.0000e-08 1.0000e-08 ];
bar_r=[10 10 10 10]
P_T=10

h_1=normrnd( 0,sqrt(0.1*(L^(-2.5))) ,[4,1])+1i*normrnd( 0,sqrt(0.1*(L^(-2.5))) ,[4,1])
h_2=normrnd( 0,sqrt(0.1*(L^(-2.5))) ,[4,1])+1i*normrnd( 0,sqrt(0.1*(L^(-2.5))) ,[4,1])
h_3=normrnd( 0,sqrt(0.1*(L^(-2.5))) ,[4,1])+1i*normrnd( 0,sqrt(0.1*(L^(-2.5))) ,[4,1])
h_4=normrnd( 0,sqrt(0.1*(L^(-2.5))) ,[4,1])+1i*normrnd( 0,sqrt(0.1*(L^(-2.5))) ,[4,1])
h_kk=cat(2,h_1 ,h_2 ,h_3, h_4)
 for n=1:4
    h_k{n}=h_kk(1:4 , n);
    n=n+1;
 end

%==========================
cvx_begin

    variable FNNK_up(N,N,K) semidefinite;%c7
    variable rho_k_up(1,1,K) semidefinite;
%==========================
%combine lots of Fkk
Fkk_up=cat(2,FNNK_up);

    up=0
   for o_up=1:4
       Fk_up{o_up}=Fkk_up(1:4,o_up+3*up:4*o_up)
       up=up+1;
   end
   tr_ace_up=0
   for t=1:K
       tr_ace_up=tr_ace_up+trace(Fk_up{t})  
   end
%====================================    
%object function
    minimize( tr_ace_up )
%==================================== 
%Constraint 
subject to 

%Constraint3
rho_k_up<=1;

%===================================================
%
%Constraint5
       c5_left_hand_up = 0;
        for k = 1:K
            sum_5_up = 0;
            for j = 1:K
                if j ~= k  
                 sum_5_up = sum_5_up +  h_k{k}' * Fk_up{j} * h_k{k};
                end
            end      
            c5_left_hand_up = c5_left_hand_up - sum_5_up+ (h_k{k}' * Fk_up{k} * h_k{k}*inv_pos(bar_r(1)))
            c5_right_hand_up= nois_var_ak_2pow(1)+ ( nois_var_dk_2pow(1)*inv_pos(rho_k_up(k)) )
            %c5_left_hand_up  >=   c5_right_hand_up
            real( c5_left_hand_up ) >=   c5_right_hand_up
        end

%===================================================   
%Constraint10
    c10_left_hand_up = 0;
        %for k = 1:K           
            sum_10_up = 0;
            for j = 1:K                  
                 sum_10_up= sum_10_up +  h_k{k}' * Fk_up{j} * h_k{k}; 
            end
            c10_left_hand_up = c10_left_hand_up + sum_10_up+nois_var_ak_2pow(1)
            c10_right_hand_up=hat_p_up*inv_pos(1-rho_k_up(k))  
            real(c10_left_hand_up)>=  c10_right_hand_up
        %end     
cvx_end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions in order:

1. Ideally, yes (if the problem you are trying to solve relies on all three of your constraints).
2. No. The variable `Constraints` is only being initialized here (by comparing if the value of the first slack variable is greater than zero), and will be a logical value (boolean value). This assumes that all slack variables will have the same array sizes.
3. the `something` variables are what you are comparing your slack variables to.
4. You can make `N` whatever you number you want, but I personally would define `N` on the first line of code.

Your `Constraints` matrix will contain 0's and 1's based off what the `something` you will be comparing your slack variables to. Constraints will essentially be appended to every time the for loop is active.

Read more about Array Comparisons in the MATLAB Documentation [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-comparison-with-relational-operators.html).

Comment: I don't understand the 3th and 4th explanation,i had add my optimal code in the question,can you please take for example to explain 3th and 4th explanation in detail?

Comment: Parts 3 & 4 are questions only you can answer, due to the nature of this problem. Again, the somethings are what you are comparing against your slack variables, and N is determined by your problem statement. Both are pre-determined from what it looks like.

Comment: still don't understand,do you have an example for any optimal formula like mine?

Comment: No I do not. The questions here are geared more towards figuring out why code may not be working. Usually, the structure of the code has been written by this point. Sorry, but I cannot help you with your optimal formula.